# Hibernate 3.2.1 and EJBQL query within query

Tags: hibernate, ejb, ejbql

I'm trying to make sure the following is supported with the EJBQL capabilities in hibernate 3.2.1, but my google-fu has failed me.
All I found was that nested queries aren't supported in EJB 2.x

Can I put a query within a query like this:

```
select count(*) from 
    (select myField from myTable group by myField having sum(case.....) ....... )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBJQL does not support subqueries in the `from` clause (you can use them in `select` and `where`), so this exact query cannot be performed. You could try rewriting the query, in your case the following should be equivalent:

```sql
select count(distinct e.myField) from myEntity e group by e.myField having ...
```

Alternatively, just use `createNativeQuery()` and use your original query without rewriting it in HQL. This of course breaks portability.

**HINT**: if you're using Eclipse, get the Hibernate plugin from http://www.jboss.org/tools or the marketplace. It allows you to write and execute queries directly from the IDE (see [query prototyping](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#d0e3241) in the Hibernate tools documentation). Other IDEs could have similar capabilities also.

Comment: Awesome, that should do it. The hibernate plugin should come in pretty handy too. Thanks!